# How would I apply this find-and-move code to all my worksheets in my excel workbook?

Tags: excel, macros, vba

```
Sub FindSchedule()
Dim xsheet As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
With ws
With Application.FindFormat.Font
    .FontStyle = "Italic"
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Cells.Find(What:="Schedule", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
Selection.Copy
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

This is the code I'm trying to have run on all my "sheets". While it does seem to function for about half the sheets, for the other half, the B1 slot just ends up blank. I'm not quite sure why this would happen,as doing it manually exactly as the macro is programmed works just fine.

As a sidenote, this macro also takes far longer than I think it should take.

Comment: `Cells.Find(...)` should be `.Cells.Find(...)` otherwise `Cells` refers to the active sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing a little bit here, but something like:

```
Sub FindSchedule()
    Dim xsheet As Worksheet

    With Application.FindFormat.Font
        .FontStyle = "Italic"
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ws.Cells.Find(What:="Schedule", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
           LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
           MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=True).Copy ws.Range("B1")

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, that made it work! Thanks! I'm guessing the Cells vs .Cells is what was causing it to sometimes work, sometimes not, and the FindFormat being inside the for loop is what was causing it to be so slow.